# HQL - Only return single object for each object property sorted by how recently the object was updated

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, playframework, hql

I have a Model called PlaylistDayStats that is related to a Playlist Model. I'm trying to do the following query, but I don't want to return two PlaylistDayStats if they are related to the same Playlist. I just want to return the first one based on which PlaylistDayStat was updated most recently.

My initial query is:

```
select p from PlaylistDayStats p where order by p.updated desc
```

How could I augment the query so that it only returns a single "p" for each "p.playlist" based on which one is returned first using "p.updated desc"?

UPDATE:

Based on Joe Taras example I did an update, where I also had to account for a need to filter down to just PlaylistDayStats of a certain user... so "p.user = johndoe@gmail.com". I also needed to maintain the order by. This new query seems to work for me, but I'm not sure if the updates I made are the most efficient way to do the query, or whether I may be screwing something else up that I'm not anticipating.

```
select p 
from PlaylistDayStats p 
where not exists( 
    select 'next'  
    from PlaylistDayStats p2  
    where p2.playlist.id = p.playlist.id  
    and p2.updated > p.updated  
    and p2.user = johndoe@gmail.com  
)  
and p.user = johndoe@gmail.com 
order by p.updated desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in HQL you can't use TOP, LIMIT, ROWNUM because are managed in different ways in owner DBMS.

So if you want get only one element you must change your query, introducing a clause of NOT EXISTS based on some conditions allow you to choose the "last" element. In your case, fixed a play list your condtion is field "updated"

Try this:

```
select p
from PlaylistDayStats p 
where not exists(
    select 'next'
    from PlayListDayStat p2
    where p2.playList = p.playList
    and p2.updated > p.updated
    and p2.user = p.user
)
and p.user = YOURVARIABLE
```

If you have other conditions about discrimination of your records, add them in where clause of sub query

Comment: I updated the query to account for a where filter, where I needed only "p" records where p.user equals a certain user. I hope by adding the same where filter to the sub query and the outer query, and also adding the order by I'm not going to break the query.

select p 
from PlaylistDayStats p 
where not exists( 
 select 'next'  
 from PlaylistDayStats p2  
 where p2.playlist.id = p.playlist.id  
 and p2.updated > p.updated  
 and p2.user = johndoe@gmail.com  
)  
and p.user = johndoe@gmail.com 
order by p.updated desc

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer with your complete request about user.